# TimescaleDB: How to use time_bucket_gapfill in CASE statement

Tags: postgresql, grafana, intervals, timescaledb

I have a hypertable with measurements which looks like this

```
| time (timestamp with time zone) | subsystem (text) | metric (text) | value (double precision) | live (boolean) |
|---------------------------------|------------------|---------------|--------------------------|----------------|
| 2021-07-01 02:09:55.766783+00   | "hwmon"          | "t_pcb"       | 28.576568603515625       | true           |
| 2021-07-01 02:10:05.759777+00   | "hwmon"          | "t_pcb"       | 28.576568603515625       | true           |
| 2021-07-01 02:10:15.760297+00   | "hwmon"          | "t_pcb"       | 28.576568603515625       | true           |
| ...                             | ...              | ...           | ...                      | ...            |
```

and a table with settings which looks like this

```
| key (text)                       | value(text) |
|----------------------------------|-------------|
| "telemetry_interval_live_v5v"    | "10s"       |
| "telemetry_interval_offline_v5v" | "2m"        |
| "telemetry_interval_live_i5v"    | "10s"       |
| "telemetry_interval_offline_i5v" | "2m"        |
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that if I'm looking at

1. A big time range: time_bucket_gapfill() should be used to reduce the number of data points requested from the DB to increase the performance and in addition have the data gaps filled with NULL so that there is no line across the gap and the gap can be seen in the plot.
2. A small time range: all points are shown with their original unmodified timestamps by not using time_bucket_gapfill()

I got this working already with the following query (within Grafana)

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN INTERVAL '$__interval' < GREATEST('$interval_live_t_pcb'::INTERVAL,'$interval_offline_t_pcb'::INTERVAL) THEN
      time
    ELSE 
      time_bucket_gapfill('$__interval',time,start => '${__from:date:iso}',finish => '${__to:date:iso}')
  END 
  AS "time",
  metric AS "metric",
  avg(value) AS "value"
FROM $satellite
WHERE
  $__timeFilter("time") AND
  live IN ($telemetry_type) AND
  "metric" = 't_pcb'
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

which is turned into the following query sent to PostgreSQL

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN INTERVAL '2m' < GREATEST('10s'::INTERVAL,'2m'::INTERVAL) THEN
      time
    ELSE 
      time_bucket_gapfill('2m',time,start => '2021-06-30T01:24:56.045Z',finish => '2021-07-02T03:40:47.173Z')
  END 
  AS "time",
  metric AS "metric",
  avg(value) AS "value"
FROM ghzlab
WHERE
  "time" BETWEEN '2021-06-30T01:24:56.045Z' AND '2021-07-02T03:40:47.173Z' AND
  live IN (true,false) AND
  "metric" = 't_pcb'
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

In the if-then-else statement I compare the displayable interval provided by Grafana ($__interval) with the expected interval between data points (sampling rate) provided via Grafana variables (constants) and based on that use time_bucket_gapfill or the unmodified data.

To make it easier to manage all the settings, I want to have the time interval settings in a table instead of Grafana variables. But if I replace replace the interval variables in the conditional expression of the if-then-else with sub queries like this

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN INTERVAL '$__interval' < GREATEST((SELECT value::INTERVAL from settings where key='telemetry_interval_offline_t_pcb'),
                                           (SELECT value::INTERVAL from settings where key='telemetry_interval_live_t_pcb')) THEN
      time
    ELSE 
      time_bucket_gapfill('$__interval',time,start => '${__from:date:iso}',finish => '${__to:date:iso}')
  END 
  AS "time",
  metric AS "metric",
  avg(value) AS "value"
FROM $satellite
WHERE
  $__timeFilter("time") AND
  live IN ($telemetry_type) AND
  "metric" = 't_pcb'
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

which is sent to PostgreSQL as

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN INTERVAL '2m' < GREATEST((SELECT value::INTERVAL from settings where key='telemetry_interval_offline_t_pcb'),
                                  (SELECT value::INTERVAL from settings where key='telemetry_interval_live_t_pcb')) THEN
      time
    ELSE 
      time_bucket_gapfill('2m',time,start => '2021-06-30T01:24:56.045Z',finish => '2021-07-02T03:40:47.173Z')
  END 
  AS "time",
  metric AS "metric",
  avg(value) AS "value"
FROM ghzlab
WHERE
  "time" BETWEEN '2021-06-30T01:24:56.045Z' AND '2021-07-02T03:40:47.173Z' AND
  live IN (true,false) AND
  "metric" = 't_pcb'
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

then I get the following error message:
**"no top level time_bucket_gapfill in group by clause"**

**What do I need to do to prevent this error?** If I replace the time_bucket_gapfill() with something else like for example with time + INTERVAL '1 day'

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN INTERVAL '2m' < GREATEST((SELECT value::INTERVAL from settings where key='telemetry_interval_offline_t_pcb'),
                                  (SELECT value::INTERVAL from settings where key='telemetry_interval_live_t_pcb')) THEN
      time
    ELSE 
      time + INTERVAL '1 day'
  END 
  AS "time",
  metric AS "metric",
  avg(value) AS "value"
FROM ghzlab
WHERE
  "time" BETWEEN '2021-06-30T01:24:56.045Z' AND '2021-07-02T03:40:47.173Z' AND
  live IN (true,false) AND
  "metric" = 't_pcb'
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

it is working without errors.

Comment: Do you know if you can use [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-with.html) in Grafana's table queries?
Have you tried to join with `settings` table instead of the subqueries?

Comment: Yes, I can use CTEs in Grafana, but it makes no difference. I get the same error with the following query
`WITH offline_interval_settings_cte AS (
  SELECT value::INTERVAL AS interval_offline
  FROM settings 
  WHERE key='telemetry_interval_offline_t_pcb'
),
live_interval_settings_cte AS (
  SELECT value::INTERVAL AS interval_live
  FROM settings 
  WHERE key='telemetry_interval_live_t_pcb'
)
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN INTERVAL '$__interval' < GREATEST((SELECT interval_offline FROM offline_interval_settings_cte), (SELECT interval_live FROM live_interval_settings_cte)) ...`

Comment: I think this problem is related to this comment from the time_bucket_gapfill function description ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68362567/timescaledb-how-to-use-time-bucket-gapfill-in-case-statement)).

"The time_bucket_gapfill must be a top-level expression in a query or subquery, as shown in the above examples. You cannot, for example, do something like round(time_bucket_gapfill(...)) or cast the result of the gapfill call (unless as a subquery where the outer query does the type cast)."

Any suggestions how I can make time_bucket_gapfill the outer expression?

Comment: Yes, my initial reaction was that `time_bucket_gapfill` cannot be used in this situation, however, you demonstrated that in one case it works with `CASE`. May be join can help.

Comment: I'll go with the solution which uses Grafana variables instead of a settings table. Thanks for your help.